# How To Change Conversation Handler State with a CallbackQueryHandler Button function

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I have a python telegram bot that sends messages with Buttons on them like this:

```
keyboard = [[telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Finish", callback_data='1'),
             telegram.InlineKeyboardButton("Edit", callback_data='2')]]
update_obj.message.reply_text(message_text, reply_markup=reply_markup,
                              parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
```

[image: Image of a Telegram Message with two buttons]

Now when the user hits the "Edit" button I want the ConversationHandler to move to another state.
Here is a part of my ConversationHandler:

```
WELCOME = 0
SEARCH = 2
EDITTITLE = 3
[...]
handler = telegram.ext.ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[telegram.ext.CommandHandler('start', start)],
    states={
        WELCOME: [
            telegram.ext.MessageHandler(filters=telegram.ext.Filters.all, callback=welcome),
            updater.dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.ext.CallbackQueryHandler(button))
        ],
        SEARCH: [
            telegram.ext.MessageHandler(filters=telegram.ext.Filters.all, callback=search),
            updater.dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.ext.CallbackQueryHandler(button))
        ], EDITTITLE: [
            telegram.ext.MessageHandler(filters=telegram.ext.Filters.all, callback=editTitle)
        ]
[...]
```

Now normally I can just return the new state in the callback function from the MesageHandler like so:

```
def search(update_obj, context):
    [...]
    return WELCOME
```

But if I return the new state in my button function it does not switch to that state. Here's the code:

```
def button(update_obj, context):
    [...]
    return EDITTITLE
```

How can I make the button change the ConversationHandler state or is there something I am missing?
Am I using the Buttons the right way?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the `CallbackQueryHandlers` wrongly to the conversation. `updater.dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.ext.CallbackQueryHandler(button))` returns `None`, so `None` will be added to the list of handlers in the states `WELCOME` and `SEARCH`. Instead it should be just `telegram.ext.CallbackQueryHandler(button)`.
It could be that there are additional issues, but I'd have to see a full minimal working example to judge that.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Hey man that’s like half a year ago ... idk I somehow already got it to work. But still thanks for the answer xD I Hope your pillow is cold on both sides tonight

Comment: Someone linked this issue in the `python-telegram-bot` group on telegram asking about something similar, that's why I answered :D Thanks, much appreciated xD